# Dynamically rendering a Facebook like button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I'm trying to add a FB like button for recommendations to an AJAX driven search page.
I've already implemented it successfully in a static template, but it seems to be more complicated to implement dynamically changing likes on a single page.
is there a way to inject the `.fb-like` template to the page dynamically **and** make facebook render it to create the necessary IFRAME? Clearly facebook does it onload, but can it be triggered manually with JS?

The original FB html to be embedded:

```
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mattat.org.il/ci/index.php/
    search/show_full/nsrecommendation/{{q}}" 
    data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" 
    data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div>
```

The `{{q}}` will be dynamically replaced with the current recommendation id

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: Thanks. You can post it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following the FB http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

you need to execute after ajax finishes

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```